# Storing Latin Characters through Linq 2 SQL on WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7, linq-to-sql, sql-server-ce

I am using SQL CE database in WP7. I have a table with nvarchar column.
When I insert entity through linq, I see symbol � stored for latin characters.

**Database Connection String:** "Data Source=test.sdf;Locale Identifier=1035"

**Expected to be stored:** Tuulisp***ää***t
**As seen through SSMS:** Tuulisp��t

I tried to set the culture of thread but issue still persists.

When I executed insert SQL statement from SSMS, it gets inserted as expected.
So why is it an issue when inserted with Linq2SQL?

Can someone throw light on what am I missing? Any workarounds or pointers?

Comment: Where do you see the square symbol (using which tool)?

Comment: Sql Server Management studio. Also when I see the raw string from database in vs debugger and console

Comment: What *exactly* do you mean by "latin characters"? Where are you getting your data from, and have you validated that it's okay *before* you insert it?

Comment: As mentioned in question, characters such as"ä" (latin alphabets). I am using linq2sql for Windows phone. I cannot see the raw sql.

Comment: @Lokeshwer: You still haven't explained where you're getting the data from. You also haven't explained how you're viewing the data afterwards.

Comment: Thanks for seeking clarification. I am fetching data from embedded flat text file with encoding ISO 8859-1. I can see latin characters in entities through vs2008 debugger. I cannot trace sql fired. Let me know if that is possible on WP7 linq2sql

Answer (score 0):

You just need to convert your data to UTF8 Encoding.
Use this class for conversion on wp7.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;


public class ISO88591Encoding : Encoding
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the name registered with the
    /// Internet Assigned Numbers Authority (IANA) for the current encoding.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>
    /// The IANA name for the current <see cref="System.Text.Encoding"/>.
    /// </returns>
    public override string WebName
    {
        get
        {
            return "iso-8859-1";
        }
    }


    private char? fallbackCharacter;

    /// <summary>
    /// A character that can be set in order to make the encoding class
    /// more fault tolerant. If this property is set, the encoding class will
    /// use this property instead of throwing an exception if an unsupported
    /// byte value is being passed for decoding.
    /// </summary>
    public char? FallbackCharacter
    {
        get { return fallbackCharacter; }
        set
        {
            fallbackCharacter = value;

            if (value.HasValue && !charToByte.ContainsKey(value.Value))
            {
                string msg = "Cannot use the character [{0}] (int value {1}) as fallback value "
                + "- the fallback character itself is not supported by the encoding.";
                msg = String.Format(msg, value.Value, (int)value.Value);
                throw new EncoderFallbackException(msg);
            }

            FallbackByte = value.HasValue ? charToByte[value.Value] : (byte?)null;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// A byte value that corresponds to the <see cref="FallbackCharacter"/>.
    /// It is used in encoding scenarios in case an unsupported character is
    /// being passed for encoding.
    /// </summary>
    public byte? FallbackByte { get; private set; }


    public ISO88591Encoding()
    {
        FallbackCharacter = '?';
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Encodes a set of characters from the specified character array into the specified byte array.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>
    /// The actual number of bytes written into <paramref name="bytes"/>.
    /// </returns>
    /// <param name="chars">The character array containing the set of characters to encode. 
    /// </param><param name="charIndex">The index of the first character to encode. 
    /// </param><param name="charCount">The number of characters to encode. 
    /// </param><param name="bytes">The byte array to contain the resulting sequence of bytes.
    /// </param><param name="byteIndex">The index at which to start writing the resulting sequence of bytes. 
    /// </param>
    public override int GetBytes(char[] chars, int charIndex, int charCount, byte[] bytes, int byteIndex)
    {
        return FallbackByte.HasValue
                 ? GetBytesWithFallBack(chars, charIndex, charCount, bytes, byteIndex)
                 : GetBytesWithoutFallback(chars, charIndex, charCount, bytes, byteIndex);
    }


    private int GetBytesWithFallBack(char[] chars, int charIndex, int charCount, byte[] bytes, int byteIndex)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < charCount; i++)
        {
            var character = chars[i + charIndex];
            byte byteValue;
            bool status = charToByte.TryGetValue(character, out byteValue);

            bytes[byteIndex + i] = status ? byteValue : FallbackByte.Value;
        }

        return charCount;
    }

    private int GetBytesWithoutFallback(char[] chars, int charIndex, int charCount, byte[] bytes, int byteIndex)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < charCount; i++)
        {
            var character = chars[i + charIndex];
            byte byteValue;
            bool status = charToByte.TryGetValue(character, out byteValue);

            if (!status)
            {
                //throw exception
                string msg =
                  "The encoding [{0}] cannot encode the character [{1}] (int value {2}). Set the FallbackCharacter property in order to suppress this exception and encode a default character instead.";
                msg = String.Format(msg, WebName, character, (int)character);
                throw new EncoderFallbackException(msg);
            }

            bytes[byteIndex + i] = byteValue;
        }

        return charCount;
    }



    /// <summary>
    /// Decodes a sequence of bytes from the specified byte array into the specified character array.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>
    /// The actual number of characters written into <paramref name="chars"/>.
    /// </returns>
    /// <param name="bytes">The byte array containing the sequence of bytes to decode. 
    /// </param><param name="byteIndex">The index of the first byte to decode. 
    /// </param><param name="byteCount">The number of bytes to decode. 
    /// </param><param name="chars">The character array to contain the resulting set of characters. 
    /// </param><param name="charIndex">The index at which to start writing the resulting set of characters. 
    /// </param>
    public override int GetChars(byte[] bytes, int byteIndex, int byteCount, char[] chars, int charIndex)
    {
        return FallbackCharacter.HasValue
                 ? GetCharsWithFallback(bytes, byteIndex, byteCount, chars, charIndex)
                 : GetCharsWithoutFallback(bytes, byteIndex, byteCount, chars, charIndex);
    }


    private int GetCharsWithFallback(byte[] bytes, int byteIndex, int byteCount, char[] chars, int charIndex)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < byteCount; i++)
        {
            byte lookupIndex = bytes[i + byteIndex];

            //if the byte value is not in our lookup array, fall back to default character
            char result = lookupIndex >= byteToChar.Length
                            ? FallbackCharacter.Value
                            : byteToChar[lookupIndex];

            chars[charIndex + i] = result;
        }

        return byteCount;
    }



    private int GetCharsWithoutFallback(byte[] bytes, int byteIndex, int byteCount, char[] chars, int charIndex)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < byteCount; i++)
        {
            byte lookupIndex = bytes[i + byteIndex];
            if (lookupIndex >= byteToChar.Length)
            {
                //throw exception
                string msg = "The encoding [{0}] cannot decode byte value [{1}]. Set the FallbackCharacter property in order to suppress this exception and decode the value as a default character instead.";
                msg = String.Format(msg, WebName, lookupIndex);
                throw new EncoderFallbackException(msg);
            }


            chars[charIndex + i] = byteToChar[lookupIndex];
        }

        return byteCount;
    }



    /// <summary>
    /// Calculates the number of bytes produced by encoding a set of characters
    /// from the specified character array.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>
    /// The number of bytes produced by encoding the specified characters. This class
    /// alwas returns the value of <paramref name="count"/>.
    /// </returns>
    public override int GetByteCount(char[] chars, int index, int count)
    {
        return count;
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Calculates the number of characters produced by decoding a sequence
    /// of bytes from the specified byte array.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>
    /// The number of characters produced by decoding the specified sequence of bytes. This class
    /// alwas returns the value of <paramref name="count"/>. 
    /// </returns>
    public override int GetCharCount(byte[] bytes, int index, int count)
    {
        return count;
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Calculates the maximum number of bytes produced by encoding the specified number of characters.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>
    /// The maximum number of bytes produced by encoding the specified number of characters. This
    /// class alwas returns the value of <paramref name="charCount"/>.
    /// </returns>
    /// <param name="charCount">The number of characters to encode. 
    /// </param>
    public override int GetMaxByteCount(int charCount)
    {
        return charCount;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Calculates the maximum number of characters produced by decoding the specified number of bytes.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>
    /// The maximum number of characters produced by decoding the specified number of bytes. This class
    /// alwas returns the value of <paramref name="byteCount"/>.
    /// </returns>
    /// <param name="byteCount">The number of bytes to decode.</param> 
    public override int GetMaxCharCount(int byteCount)
    {
        return byteCount;
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the number of characters that are supported by this encoding.
    /// This property returns a maximum value of 256, as the encoding class
    /// only supports single byte encodings (1 byte == 256 possible values).
    /// </summary>
    public static int CharacterCount
    {
        get { return byteToChar.Length; }
    }


    #region Character Table

    /// <summary>
    /// This table contains characters in an array. The index within the
    /// array corresponds to the encoding's mapping of bytes to characters
    /// (e.g. if a byte value of 5 is used to encode the character 'x', this
    /// character will be stored at the array index 5.
    /// </summary>
    private static char[] byteToChar = new char[]
{
  (char)0 /* byte 0 */  ,
  (char)1 /* byte 1 */  ,
  (char)2 /* byte 2 */  ,
  (char)3 /* byte 3 */  ,
  (char)4 /* byte 4 */  ,
  (char)5 /* byte 5 */  ,
  (char)6 /* byte 6 */  ,
  (char)7 /* byte 7 */  ,
  (char)8 /* byte 8 */  ,
  (char)9 /* byte 9 */  ,
  (char)10 /* byte 10 */  ,
  (char)11 /* byte 11 */  ,
  (char)12 /* byte 12 */  ,
  (char)13 /* byte 13 */  ,
  (char)14 /* byte 14 */  ,
  (char)15 /* byte 15 */  ,
  (char)16 /* byte 16 */  ,
  (char)17 /* byte 17 */  ,
  (char)18 /* byte 18 */  ,
  (char)19 /* byte 19 */  ,
  (char)20 /* byte 20 */  ,
  (char)21 /* byte 21 */  ,
  (char)22 /* byte 22 */  ,
  (char)23 /* byte 23 */  ,
  (char)24 /* byte 24 */  ,
  (char)25 /* byte 25 */  ,
  (char)26 /* byte 26 */  ,
  (char)27 /* byte 27 */  ,
  (char)28 /* byte 28 */  ,
  (char)29 /* byte 29 */  ,
  (char)30 /* byte 30 */  ,
  (char)31 /* byte 31 */  ,
  (char)32 /* byte 32 */  ,
  (char)33 /* byte 33 */  ,
  (char)34 /* byte 34 */  ,
  (char)35 /* byte 35 */  ,
  (char)36 /* byte 36 */  ,
  (char)37 /* byte 37 */  ,
  (char)38 /* byte 38 */  ,
  (char)39 /* byte 39 */  ,
  (char)40 /* byte 40 */  ,
  (char)41 /* byte 41 */  ,
  (char)42 /* byte 42 */  ,
  (char)43 /* byte 43 */  ,
  (char)44 /* byte 44 */  ,
  (char)45 /* byte 45 */  ,
  (char)46 /* byte 46 */  ,
  (char)47 /* byte 47 */  ,
  (char)48 /* byte 48 */  ,
  (char)49 /* byte 49 */  ,
  (char)50 /* byte 50 */  ,
  (char)51 /* byte 51 */  ,
  (char)52 /* byte 52 */  ,
  (char)53 /* byte 53 */  ,
  (char)54 /* byte 54 */  ,
  (char)55 /* byte 55 */  ,
  (char)56 /* byte 56 */  ,
  (char)57 /* byte 57 */  ,
  (char)58 /* byte 58 */  ,
  (char)59 /* byte 59 */  ,
  (char)60 /* byte 60 */  ,
  (char)61 /* byte 61 */  ,
  (char)62 /* byte 62 */  ,
  (char)63 /* byte 63 */  ,
  (char)64 /* byte 64 */  ,
  (char)65 /* byte 65 */  ,
  (char)66 /* byte 66 */  ,
  (char)67 /* byte 67 */  ,
  (char)68 /* byte 68 */  ,
  (char)69 /* byte 69 */  ,
  (char)70 /* byte 70 */  ,
  (char)71 /* byte 71 */  ,
  (char)72 /* byte 72 */  ,
  (char)73 /* byte 73 */  ,
  (char)74 /* byte 74 */  ,
  (char)75 /* byte 75 */  ,
  (char)76 /* byte 76 */  ,
  (char)77 /* byte 77 */  ,
  (char)78 /* byte 78 */  ,
  (char)79 /* byte 79 */  ,
  (char)80 /* byte 80 */  ,
  (char)81 /* byte 81 */  ,
  (char)82 /* byte 82 */  ,
  (char)83 /* byte 83 */  ,
  (char)84 /* byte 84 */  ,
  (char)85 /* byte 85 */  ,
  (char)86 /* byte 86 */  ,
  (char)87 /* byte 87 */  ,
  (char)88 /* byte 88 */  ,
  (char)89 /* byte 89 */  ,
  (char)90 /* byte 90 */  ,
  (char)91 /* byte 91 */  ,
  (char)92 /* byte 92 */  ,
  (char)93 /* byte 93 */  ,
  (char)94 /* byte 94 */  ,
  (char)95 /* byte 95 */  ,
  (char)96 /* byte 96 */  ,
  (char)97 /* byte 97 */  ,
  (char)98 /* byte 98 */  ,
  (char)99 /* byte 99 */  ,
  (char)100 /* byte 100 */  ,
  (char)101 /* byte 101 */  ,
  (char)102 /* byte 102 */  ,
  (char)103 /* byte 103 */  ,
  (char)104 /* byte 104 */  ,
  (char)105 /* byte 105 */  ,
  (char)106 /* byte 106 */  ,
  (char)107 /* byte 107 */  ,
  (char)108 /* byte 108 */  ,
  (char)109 /* byte 109 */  ,
  (char)110 /* byte 110 */  ,
  (char)111 /* byte 111 */  ,
  (char)112 /* byte 112 */  ,
  (char)113 /* byte 113 */  ,
  (char)114 /* byte 114 */  ,
  (char)115 /* byte 115 */  ,
  (char)116 /* byte 116 */  ,
  (char)117 /* byte 117 */  ,
  (char)118 /* byte 118 */  ,
  (char)119 /* byte 119 */  ,
  (char)120 /* byte 120 */  ,
  (char)121 /* byte 121 */  ,
  (char)122 /* byte 122 */  ,
  (char)123 /* byte 123 */  ,
  (char)124 /* byte 124 */  ,
  (char)125 /* byte 125 */  ,
  (char)126 /* byte 126 */  ,
  (char)127 /* byte 127 */  ,
  (char)128 /* byte 128 */  ,
  (char)129 /* byte 129 */  ,
  (char)130 /* byte 130 */  ,
  (char)131 /* byte 131 */  ,
  (char)132 /* byte 132 */  ,
  (char)133 /* byte 133 */  ,
  (char)134 /* byte 134 */  ,
  (char)135 /* byte 135 */  ,
  (char)136 /* byte 136 */  ,
  (char)137 /* byte 137 */  ,
  (char)138 /* byte 138 */  ,
  (char)139 /* byte 139 */  ,
  (char)140 /* byte 140 */  ,
  (char)141 /* byte 141 */  ,
  (char)142 /* byte 142 */  ,
  (char)143 /* byte 143 */  ,
  (char)144 /* byte 144 */  ,
  (char)145 /* byte 145 */  ,
  (char)146 /* byte 146 */  ,
  (char)147 /* byte 147 */  ,
  (char)148 /* byte 148 */  ,
  (char)149 /* byte 149 */  ,
  (char)150 /* byte 150 */  ,
  (char)151 /* byte 151 */  ,
  (char)152 /* byte 152 */  ,
  (char)153 /* byte 153 */  ,
  (char)154 /* byte 154 */  ,
  (char)155 /* byte 155 */  ,
  (char)156 /* byte 156 */  ,
  (char)157 /* byte 157 */  ,
  (char)158 /* byte 158 */  ,
  (char)159 /* byte 159 */  ,
  (char)160 /* byte 160 */  ,
  (char)161 /* byte 161 */  ,
  (char)162 /* byte 162 */  ,
  (char)163 /* byte 163 */  ,
  (char)164 /* byte 164 */  ,
  (char)165 /* byte 165 */  ,
  (char)166 /* byte 166 */  ,
  (char)167 /* byte 167 */  ,
  (char)168 /* byte 168 */  ,
  (char)169 /* byte 169 */  ,
  (char)170 /* byte 170 */  ,
  (char)171 /* byte 171 */  ,
  (char)172 /* byte 172 */  ,
  (char)173 /* byte 173 */  ,
  (char)174 /* byte 174 */  ,
  (char)175 /* byte 175 */  ,
  (char)176 /* byte 176 */  ,
  (char)177 /* byte 177 */  ,
  (char)178 /* byte 178 */  ,
  (char)179 /* byte 179 */  ,
  (char)180 /* byte 180 */  ,
  (char)181 /* byte 181 */  ,
  (char)182 /* byte 182 */  ,
  (char)183 /* byte 183 */  ,
  (char)184 /* byte 184 */  ,
  (char)185 /* byte 185 */  ,
  (char)186 /* byte 186 */  ,
  (char)187 /* byte 187 */  ,
  (char)188 /* byte 188 */  ,
  (char)189 /* byte 189 */  ,
  (char)190 /* byte 190 */  ,
  (char)191 /* byte 191 */  ,
  (char)192 /* byte 192 */  ,
  (char)193 /* byte 193 */  ,
  (char)194 /* byte 194 */  ,
  (char)195 /* byte 195 */  ,
  (char)196 /* byte 196 */  ,
  (char)197 /* byte 197 */  ,
  (char)198 /* byte 198 */  ,
  (char)199 /* byte 199 */  ,
  (char)200 /* byte 200 */  ,
  (char)201 /* byte 201 */  ,
  (char)202 /* byte 202 */  ,
  (char)203 /* byte 203 */  ,
  (char)204 /* byte 204 */  ,
  (char)205 /* byte 205 */  ,
  (char)206 /* byte 206 */  ,
  (char)207 /* byte 207 */  ,
  (char)208 /* byte 208 */  ,
  (char)209 /* byte 209 */  ,
  (char)210 /* byte 210 */  ,
  (char)211 /* byte 211 */  ,
  (char)212 /* byte 212 */  ,
  (char)213 /* byte 213 */  ,
  (char)214 /* byte 214 */  ,
  (char)215 /* byte 215 */  ,
  (char)216 /* byte 216 */  ,
  (char)217 /* byte 217 */  ,
  (char)218 /* byte 218 */  ,
  (char)219 /* byte 219 */  ,
  (char)220 /* byte 220 */  ,
  (char)221 /* byte 221 */  ,
  (char)222 /* byte 222 */  ,
  (char)223 /* byte 223 */  ,
  (char)224 /* byte 224 */  ,
  (char)225 /* byte 225 */  ,
  (char)226 /* byte 226 */  ,
  (char)227 /* byte 227 */  ,
  (char)228 /* byte 228 */  ,
  (char)229 /* byte 229 */  ,
  (char)230 /* byte 230 */  ,
  (char)231 /* byte 231 */  ,
  (char)232 /* byte 232 */  ,
  (char)233 /* byte 233 */  ,
  (char)234 /* byte 234 */  ,
  (char)235 /* byte 235 */  ,
  (char)236 /* byte 236 */  ,
  (char)237 /* byte 237 */  ,
  (char)238 /* byte 238 */  ,
  (char)239 /* byte 239 */  ,
  (char)240 /* byte 240 */  ,
  (char)241 /* byte 241 */  ,
  (char)242 /* byte 242 */  ,
  (char)243 /* byte 243 */  ,
  (char)244 /* byte 244 */  ,
  (char)245 /* byte 245 */  ,
  (char)246 /* byte 246 */  ,
  (char)247 /* byte 247 */  ,
  (char)248 /* byte 248 */  ,
  (char)249 /* byte 249 */  ,
  (char)250 /* byte 250 */  ,
  (char)251 /* byte 251 */  ,
  (char)252 /* byte 252 */  ,
  (char)253 /* byte 253 */  ,
  (char)254 /* byte 254 */  ,
  (char)255 /* byte 255 */  
};

    #endregion


    #region Byte Lookup Dictionary

    /// <summary>
    /// This dictionary is used to resolve byte values for a given character.
    /// </summary>
    private static Dictionary<char, byte> charToByte = new Dictionary<char, byte>
{
  { (char)0, 0 },
  { (char)1, 1 },
  { (char)2, 2 },
  { (char)3, 3 },
  { (char)4, 4 },
  { (char)5, 5 },
  { (char)6, 6 },
  { (char)7, 7 },
  { (char)8, 8 },
  { (char)9, 9 },
  { (char)10, 10 },
  { (char)11, 11 },
  { (char)12, 12 },
  { (char)13, 13 },
  { (char)14, 14 },
  { (char)15, 15 },
  { (char)16, 16 },
  { (char)17, 17 },
  { (char)18, 18 },
  { (char)19, 19 },
  { (char)20, 20 },
  { (char)21, 21 },
  { (char)22, 22 },
  { (char)23, 23 },
  { (char)24, 24 },
  { (char)25, 25 },
  { (char)26, 26 },
  { (char)27, 27 },
  { (char)28, 28 },
  { (char)29, 29 },
  { (char)30, 30 },
  { (char)31, 31 },
  { (char)32, 32 },
  { (char)33, 33 },
  { (char)34, 34 },
  { (char)35, 35 },
  { (char)36, 36 },
  { (char)37, 37 },
  { (char)38, 38 },
  { (char)39, 39 },
  { (char)40, 40 },
  { (char)41, 41 },
  { (char)42, 42 },
  { (char)43, 43 },
  { (char)44, 44 },
  { (char)45, 45 },
  { (char)46, 46 },
  { (char)47, 47 },
  { (char)48, 48 },
  { (char)49, 49 },
  { (char)50, 50 },
  { (char)51, 51 },
  { (char)52, 52 },
  { (char)53, 53 },
  { (char)54, 54 },
  { (char)55, 55 },
  { (char)56, 56 },
  { (char)57, 57 },
  { (char)58, 58 },
  { (char)59, 59 },
  { (char)60, 60 },
  { (char)61, 61 },
  { (char)62, 62 },
  { (char)63, 63 },
  { (char)64, 64 },
  { (char)65, 65 },
  { (char)66, 66 },
  { (char)67, 67 },
  { (char)68, 68 },
  { (char)69, 69 },
  { (char)70, 70 },
  { (char)71, 71 },
  { (char)72, 72 },
  { (char)73, 73 },
  { (char)74, 74 },
  { (char)75, 75 },
  { (char)76, 76 },
  { (char)77, 77 },
  { (char)78, 78 },
  { (char)79, 79 },
  { (char)80, 80 },
  { (char)81, 81 },
  { (char)82, 82 },
  { (char)83, 83 },
  { (char)84, 84 },
  { (char)85, 85 },
  { (char)86, 86 },
  { (char)87, 87 },
  { (char)88, 88 },
  { (char)89, 89 },
  { (char)90, 90 },
  { (char)91, 91 },
  { (char)92, 92 },
  { (char)93, 93 },
  { (char)94, 94 },
  { (char)95, 95 },
  { (char)96, 96 },
  { (char)97, 97 },
  { (char)98, 98 },
  { (char)99, 99 },
  { (char)100, 100 },
  { (char)101, 101 },
  { (char)102, 102 },
  { (char)103, 103 },
  { (char)104, 104 },
  { (char)105, 105 },
  { (char)106, 106 },
  { (char)107, 107 },
  { (char)108, 108 },
  { (char)109, 109 },
  { (char)110, 110 },
  { (char)111, 111 },
  { (char)112, 112 },
  { (char)113, 113 },
  { (char)114, 114 },
  { (char)115, 115 },
  { (char)116, 116 },
  { (char)117, 117 },
  { (char)118, 118 },
  { (char)119, 119 },
  { (char)120, 120 },
  { (char)121, 121 },
  { (char)122, 122 },
  { (char)123, 123 },
  { (char)124, 124 },
  { (char)125, 125 },
  { (char)126, 126 },
  { (char)127, 127 },
  { (char)128, 128 },
  { (char)129, 129 },
  { (char)130, 130 },
  { (char)131, 131 },
  { (char)132, 132 },
  { (char)133, 133 },
  { (char)134, 134 },
  { (char)135, 135 },
  { (char)136, 136 },
  { (char)137, 137 },
  { (char)138, 138 },
  { (char)139, 139 },
  { (char)140, 140 },
  { (char)141, 141 },
  { (char)142, 142 },
  { (char)143, 143 },
  { (char)144, 144 },
  { (char)145, 145 },
  { (char)146, 146 },
  { (char)147, 147 },
  { (char)148, 148 },
  { (char)149, 149 },
  { (char)150, 150 },
  { (char)151, 151 },
  { (char)152, 152 },
  { (char)153, 153 },
  { (char)154, 154 },
  { (char)155, 155 },
  { (char)156, 156 },
  { (char)157, 157 },
  { (char)158, 158 },
  { (char)159, 159 },
  { (char)160, 160 },
  { (char)161, 161 },
  { (char)162, 162 },
  { (char)163, 163 },
  { (char)164, 164 },
  { (char)165, 165 },
  { (char)166, 166 },
  { (char)167, 167 },
  { (char)168, 168 },
  { (char)169, 169 },
  { (char)170, 170 },
  { (char)171, 171 },
  { (char)172, 172 },
  { (char)173, 173 },
  { (char)174, 174 },
  { (char)175, 175 },
  { (char)176, 176 },
  { (char)177, 177 },
  { (char)178, 178 },
  { (char)179, 179 },
  { (char)180, 180 },
  { (char)181, 181 },
  { (char)182, 182 },
  { (char)183, 183 },
  { (char)184, 184 },
  { (char)185, 185 },
  { (char)186, 186 },
  { (char)187, 187 },
  { (char)188, 188 },
  { (char)189, 189 },
  { (char)190, 190 },
  { (char)191, 191 },
  { (char)192, 192 },
  { (char)193, 193 },
  { (char)194, 194 },
  { (char)195, 195 },
  { (char)196, 196 },
  { (char)197, 197 },
  { (char)198, 198 },
  { (char)199, 199 },
  { (char)200, 200 },
  { (char)201, 201 },
  { (char)202, 202 },
  { (char)203, 203 },
  { (char)204, 204 },
  { (char)205, 205 },
  { (char)206, 206 },
  { (char)207, 207 },
  { (char)208, 208 },
  { (char)209, 209 },
  { (char)210, 210 },
  { (char)211, 211 },
  { (char)212, 212 },
  { (char)213, 213 },
  { (char)214, 214 },
  { (char)215, 215 },
  { (char)216, 216 },
  { (char)217, 217 },
  { (char)218, 218 },
  { (char)219, 219 },
  { (char)220, 220 },
  { (char)221, 221 },
  { (char)222, 222 },
  { (char)223, 223 },
  { (char)224, 224 },
  { (char)225, 225 },
  { (char)226, 226 },
  { (char)227, 227 },
  { (char)228, 228 },
  { (char)229, 229 },
  { (char)230, 230 },
  { (char)231, 231 },
  { (char)232, 232 },
  { (char)233, 233 },
  { (char)234, 234 },
  { (char)235, 235 },
  { (char)236, 236 },
  { (char)237, 237 },
  { (char)238, 238 },
  { (char)239, 239 },
  { (char)240, 240 },
  { (char)241, 241 },
  { (char)242, 242 },
  { (char)243, 243 },
  { (char)244, 244 },
  { (char)245, 245 },
  { (char)246, 246 },
  { (char)247, 247 },
  { (char)248, 248 },
  { (char)249, 249 },
  { (char)250, 250 },
  { (char)251, 251 },
  { (char)252, 252 },
  { (char)253, 253 },
  { (char)254, 254 },
  { (char)255, 255 }
};

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: We can use Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1") instead. I have used correct encoding to read. I can see the correct encoding before I save context.

Comment: You can't use Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1") on WP because Silverlight supports only UTF and Unicode encodings. So you should use custom implementation.